# Updating site with git push, browser still loads old cached version

Tags: javascript, git, google-chrome, caching

Git has made updating my site a hell of a lot easier and quicker. I love it.
However, it seems when updating files with git, my browser seems to cling to old cacheable files much longer than it should.
I have no idea if this is just my browser, if it's a quirk of git, or if it's just a problem that affects only me for some other reason.

A couple days ago I found a bug on my site, so I fixed it and pushed a new version of the affected js file to my site.
When I do this, I find if I don't hit f5, then it'll load the old js file. So I always hit f5 and think nothing of it.
But for users of my site, they are probably having the same experience... which isn't good.

So I updated the js file 2 days ago and refreshed the home page, checked it was working and left it.
Just now, I checked another page on the site, loading the exact same js file and it was still using the old cached version. I hit f5, it now loads the new one.
Is there any way I can force all browsers to forget the cached version of old files? I figured this should just happen automatically after a cache's short lifetime.

Here's the headers from chrome:
[image]

As you can see, the cache control max-age is stupidly high. My server runs with nginx+apache, and a backend system called Vesta Control Panel (VestaCP).
If I fix the cache control on the backend, how do I then tell all of my user's browsers to forget the seemingly unforgettable cached version?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your setup. If your index page is HTML, you'll want to set the server cache to expire very quickly on HTML files, so it will reload your index page frequently. (This isn't an issue with an index.php, as it should reload every time). Then you'll want to filerev your resource files.

For instance, you can use grunt, gulp, or something similar that will append a unique string at the end of the filenames for all your resources, so `script.js` becomes `script.1a34be4sde4.js` and then the next update becomes `script.3ezseasd4sad.js` and so on. Or you could manually rename them, adding 1 each time (`script-001.js`, `script-002.js`, etc. - although with many files this would be a pain).

This way you can keep your max-age stupidly high and the user won't have to download that version of the file again. But when your index page points them to an updated version (new filename), they'll go grab the new version and cache it stupidly long.

The problem comes with using `git push` to update the site. To keep your repo clean, there are a few things you could do. What I'd probably lean toward is a post-receive hook script on the server that would checkout the pushed branch to a staging folder, run a build script, and move the final version to the deployment folder.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of cache-busting techniques that you can use, none of which are particularly linked to git (and some may be anathema to it).

In your index.html, you could use a query cachebuster:

```
<script src="/js/core.js?cache=12345">
```

Which works in some cases (most browsers, AFAIK, won't re-use cached files if the query string is different). This means you have to change your index.html every time you update stuff. There's plenty other ways to do cache busting, google around and you'll probably find a dozen at least, each of which is the "best".

Personally, I use [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) in combination with [gulp-inject](https://github.com/klei/gulp-inject) in my build process. gulp-rev will create a hash-based uniqid for the filename (so it renames core.js to core-ad234af.js), and then gulp-inject changes index.html so it pulls that file in, instead of core.js. I only do this when doing a production build (since in dev, I have cache-control set to 0).

But this all works because I don't do git push to deploy - I use git to get the source to my production server, and then build on that server with the production flag set.